# In a VSIX package, how can I reuse the existing MEF for my dependency container?

Tags: mef, vsix

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension package (VSIX).  It uses MEF, as is usual to plug into VS.

Instead of creating another container, is there a way for me to reuse the MEF container, exporting and importing my own internal classes?  I've tried [Export(IMyInternalThing)] and [Import] IMyInternalThing thing;  but the import is never satisfied.  And this is inside a class that IS being used by VS and MEF to fulfill one of its own imports successfully.

So why doesn't MEF fulfill my import?